# Django : get entries of today and SplitDateTime Widget?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I used : SplitDateTimeWidget to split DateTime field ,

```
appointment = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.SplitDateTimeWidget)
```

In the template side i manage to use datePicker and TimePicker for each field  , using jQuery .

When i try to filter the entries regarding to today date as in this code :

```
d = datetime.date.today()
entries = Entry.objects.filter(appointment__year=d.year ,appointment__month=d.month ,appointment__day=d.day )
```

It shows the entries of yesterday 17 aug :( which is really weird !

I Tried to split the Date and Time in the model , i got the same result as well !

Any idea how to fix this ?!

Comment: It's still August, 17th where I am. What's the time of your server?

Comment: OPS , LOL i totally forget to change the TimeZone in settings.py sorry .

Answer (score 2):

Fix your timezone settings, in `settings.py TIME_ZONE`

**Default:**  `'America/Chicago'`

Some excerpts of useful info from [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone):

> A string representing the time zone
>   for this installation. [See available
>   choices.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datetime-keywords.html#DATETIME-TIMEZONE-SET-TABLE)
>
> *(...)*
>
> **Note that this is the time zone to which Django will convert all
>   dates/times** -- not necessarily the
>   timezone of the server.
>
> *(...)*
>
> Django cannot reliably use alternate
>   time zones in a Windows environment.
>   If you're running Django on Windows,
>   this variable must be set to match the
>   system timezone.

Comment: Thank you , Already figured the issue and fixed it , am using Django on Ubuntu , BSD and ArchLinux mostly .. don't like to deal with windows as dev environment .... BTW any solution to change the time zone regarding the visitor or current user ?!
Regards

Comment: @Hamza: One generally uses a template filter to do that. See here http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/183/ for an example of filter you can use. Please mark answer as accepted so your question can have a correct answer